# SQL : Data filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have BillItem table with data. Below is the table

```
+------------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| BillItemId | BillId | PayTypeId | GrossAmount | TaxAmount | TotalAmount |
+------------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|        430 |    415 |        56 |       60.00 |      9.90 |       69.90 |
|        431 |    416 |        57 |     3125.00 |    156.25 |     3281.25 |
|        432 |    417 |        57 |     6500.00 |    325.00 |     6825.00 |
|        433 |    418 |        57 |     1750.00 |     87.50 |     1837.50 |
|        434 |    419 |        58 |     2220.00 |    111.00 |     2331.00 |
|        435 |    416 |        58 |     1776.00 |     88.80 |     1864.80 |
|        436 |    420 |        61 |     6000.00 |    300.00 |     6300.00 |
|        437 |    421 |        60 |     5270.00 |    263.50 |     5533.50 |
|        438 |    421 |        61 |     3600.00 |    180.00 |     3780.00 |
+------------+--------+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

But From BillItem table I want result like shown in below table

```
+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| BillId |  56   |   57    |   58    |   60    |   61    | GrossAmount | TaxAmount | TotalAmount |
+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|    415 | 60.00 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |       60.00 |      9.90 |       69.90 |
|    416 |     0 | 3125.00 | 1776.00 |       0 |       0 |     4901.00 |    245.05 |     5146.05 |
|    417 |     0 | 6500.00 |       0 |       0 |       0 |     6500.00 |    325.00 |     6825.00 |
|    418 |     0 | 1750.00 |       0 |       0 |       0 |     1750.00 |     87.50 |     1837.50 |
|    419 |     0 |       0 | 2220.00 |       0 |       0 |     2220.00 |    111.00 |     2331.00 |
|    420 |     0 |       0 |       0 |       0 | 6000.00 |     6000.00 |    300.00 |     6300.00 |
|    421 |     0 |       0 |       0 | 5270.00 | 3600.00 |     8870.00 |    443.50 |     9313.50 |
+--------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

As shown in result table, want data by BillId and sum of its relative components. I am new to sql and not getting how to find result like this. Please help me for it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL server..

Comment: It's better to show sample data as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Data from screenshot can't be used to setup a test bed via Copy & Paste

Comment: It looks like you already have tables; you can use [this handy site](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to turn them into text the site can cope with.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
  BillId,sum(GrossAmount),sum(TaxAmount),sum(TotalAmount),PayTypeId
  from BillItem 
  group by BillId
)
as tablo
pivot
(
  sum(GrossAmount)
  for PayTypeId in ([56],[57],[58],[59],[60],[61])
) as p
order by BillId
```

Comment: If PayTypeId is not fixed then can we write query to fetch it in bracket ??

Comment: And also I want sum of PayType value If its added multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of conditional aggregations:

```
select BillId,
       sum(case when PayTypeId = 56 then GrossAmount else 0 end) as grossamount_56,
       sum(case when PayTypeId = 57 then GrossAmount else 0 end) as grossamount_57,
       sum(case when PayTypeId = 58 then GrossAmount else 0 end) as grossamount_58,
       sum(case when PayTypeId = 59 then GrossAmount else 0 end) as grossamount_59,
       sum(case when PayTypeId = 60 then GrossAmount else 0 end) as grossamount_60,
       sum(case when PayTypeId = 61 then GrossAmount else 0 end) as grossamount_1,
       sum(GrossAmount) as grossamount,
       sum(TaxAmount) as taxamount,
       sum(TotalAmount) as totalamount
from BillItem bi
group by BillId;
```

Comment: Actually, PayTypeId are not fixed, its dynamic